# Force geoserver to SRID 0

Tags: geometry, postgis, srid

I'm developing a gis solution which uses only geometry data.

I designed my spatial DB with PostGIS and now I'm performing some trials connecting the DB with GeoServer map server (using the administration page).

In the layer definition of the administration tool there is the mandatory field SRS(Spatial Reference System) to set with the appropriate SRID

I'd like to know which is the default SRID value to set in order to take into account the geometry type. I read that should be 0, but it doesn't work....

Thanks

nico

Comment: Why would you use SRID=0? Are they test geometries that don't exist? If it is real data, use a real SRID.

Comment: Hi, I have to display some line and point on a flat plane, nothing related to the world..... Which means real SRID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. GeoTools (and GeoServer) provide EPSG:404000 for generic 2D systems: "Wildcard 2D cartesian plane in metric unit"